# Gboard keeps changing itself to AZERTY

Tags: keyboard, languages, gboard

This started happening recently. My keyboard keeps changing itself to AZERTY-Francais-Afrique layout, and I don't know how to make it stop. Samsung Galaxy J7. Android 7.1.1

Comment: Have you checked the setting from the phone for the Gboard virtual keyboard? Perhaps also relevant, what is your usual keyboard layout? Are you using multi-languages?

Comment: English is the only language that is enabled in gboard. The default keyboard says "Multilingual typing -Gboard"